# Using COUNT in SQLite3

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to access the details from two joined tables in SQL of 5 categories, for one of which I need to run the COUNT function. I am able to access the details, until I run the count function, after which I am limited to a single result. I have also tried using COUNT(*) as... - but this hasn't worked. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT name, location, grade_1996, COUNT(voter_id)
FROM votes
JOIN congress_members
ON congress_members.id=politician_id
WHERE grade_current < 9;
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired reult.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by`.  Perhaps this is what you intend:

```
SELECT name, location, grade_1996, COUNT(voter_id)
FROM votes JOIN
     congress_members
     ON congress_members.id=politician_id
WHERE grade_current < 9
GROUP BY name, location, grade_1996;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select name,
    location,
    grade_1996,
    COUNT(voter_id)
from votes
join congress_members on congress_members.id = politician_id
where grade_current < 9
group by name,
    location,
    grade_1996;
```